# What's the murder-to-renovation ratio?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

It seems like every time I renovate a building, my Awareness jumps a good 20% give or take.  Killing guards and otherwise causing a disturbance to the peace seems to give me far less, but I've been a bit lackadaisical about how many guards I off if the situation calls for it.

Approximately how many people can I kill before I've accrued as much Awareness as renovating a building?

Comment: [tag:Murder], may not be the tag we need. But it's the Tag we Deserve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have observed that from having 0% Templar Awareness, it takes 5 high-profile kills (where guards *see* you make the kill) to get it to fill up 1/8 the way (to the corner of the meter).   **Janissaries** are worth **two** normal kills.  That would equate to 40 high-profile kills to get to 100% Templar Awareness.  Renovations add 20% to your awareness taking 5 renovations to get to 100% Templar Awareness.

By my calculations:

Murder: **40** kills/**100%** awareness
Renovations: **5** renovations/**100%** awareness

Murder-To-Renovation Ratio: **40** kills/**5** renovations == **8** kills/**1** renovation == **8.0**

Comment: Note, I have 100% synchronization in the game.  So this may or may not affect the ratio.  I don't think it did.

Comment: It's not like the other games, where when you ended the game, they gave you an item that made your awareness fall to 0 and stay to it.

Comment: Nicely done! 3chr